# How to change the border line color refresh the page

Tags: javascript, css, colors, border

I applied css border color in site. I want to  chnage  the border color in each time refresh the page .how to write the code in javascript.

Comment: http://www.devcurry.com/2010/08/generate-random-colors-using-javascript.html

Comment: this is changing  continuously i want only refresh the page the border color ll change

Answer (score 1):

```
function chgbord()
{
 var colorarr=new Array('red','green','blue');
 document.getElementById('id').style.border="border:1px solid "+colorarr[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)];
}
```

and use `<body load="chgbord()">`

Comment: its not working.i have found the code in php but how to write  this code in javascript <?php
function getBackgroundColor() {
  switch(rand(0, 3)) {
    case 1:
      return "#f00";
    case 2:
      return "#0f0";
    case 3:
      return "#00f";
    default:
      return "#fff";
  }
}
?>
<html>
<head><title>test page</title></head>
<body style="background-color: <?php echo getBackgroundColor(); ?>">
here comes the body
</body>
</html>

Comment: Error: missing ) after argument list
Source File:  
Line: 9, Column: 30
Source Code:
 var colorarr=new Array('red,'green','blue');

Comment: Sorry i missed quote ' near red

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different option:

HTML:

```
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.myDiv { border-top: 5px solid #333; }
```

Function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

  $(document).ready(function() {
      ChangeBorder(); 
  }); 

  function ChangeBorder() {

      var colors = ["#ff0000", "#00ff00", "#0000ff", "#731472" ];
      var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);           
      $('.myDiv').css("border-color", colors[rand]); 

  }

</script>
```